# Svg rotation animation with css not working on ie or edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer, animation, svg, microsoft-edge

I'm working on an animation of a spinner on a svg.
Unfortunately, I'm having trouble with ie or edge. Every other browser are supported.

Here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/skjnldsv/pen/oxyjoQ

As you can see the opacity animation works, but not the rotate.
Is there some kind of prefix i'm missing, or is the svg support broken in ie/edge?

Thanks

here is the two svg, first one not working, second one is ok.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="50" width="50">
    <style>
        .spinner {
            transform-origin: 25px 25px;
            -webkit-transform-origin: 25px 25px;
            animation: loading-spin .8s infinite linear;
            -webkit-animation: loading-spin .8s infinite linear
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes loading-spin {
            100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
        }
        @keyframes loading-spin {
            100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
        }
    </style>
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="a">
            <path d="M0 0h25v25H0z" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g fill="none">
        <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="23" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity=".5" />
        <circle class="spinner" cx="25" cy="25" r="23" clip-path="url(#a)" stroke="#191919" stroke-width="3" />
    </g>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="50" width="50">
    <style>
    .spinner2 {
        transform-origin: 25px 25px;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 25px 25px;
        animation: loading-spin2 .8s infinite linear;
        -webkit-animation: loading-spin2 .8s infinite linear
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes loading-spin2 {
       100% { opacity:0; }
    }
    @keyframes loading-spin2 {
       100% { opacity:0; }
    }
    </style>
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="a">
            <path d="M0 0h25v25H0z" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g fill="none">
        <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="23" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity=".5" />
        <circle class="spinner2" cx="25" cy="25" r="23" clip-path="url(#a)" stroke="#191919" stroke-width="3" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue myself. After digging around I found out that CSS transforms in SVG's are not supported by Edge at the moment. It's really annoying but your only option is to use Javascript to animate an SVG on Edge.

You can follow the status of the feature on the Microsoft Edge site.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/supportcsstransformsonsvg/